# AWS launch new instance using Ubuntu 22.04: image has more volumes than instances allows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS launch new instance using Ubuntu 22.04:

```
The selected AMI contains more instance store volumes 
than the instance allows. Only the first 0 instance
store volumes from the AMI will be accessible from the 
instance
```

What does it mean?  does an AMI have volumes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EC2 instances can have two basic types of volumes: EBS ([Elastic Block Store](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/)) and [Instance Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html). [This article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/instance-store-vs-ebs/) spells out the differences, but in a nutshell, EBS volumes are network attached storage that are independent of an instance, while Instance Store volumes are local block storage volumes that are not persistent (e.g. when the instance is terminated, the instance store volume is lost).

You ask if an AMI has volumes. An AMI basically *is* one or more volumes. The AMI is a snapshot of a disk in a particular state. These days, most modern AMIs use EBS storage for the root volume; that is, the volume that contains the operating system kernel that an instance boots from. It used to be commonplace to use Instance Store for the root volume, but EBS has become nearly as fast, more secure, and more reliable than Instance Store, so the use cases for Instance Store volumes are dwindling.

With all that said, I'm quite surprised that you're seeing this error. The error message suggests that the AMI includes Instance Store but the instance type you selected does not support Instance Store (many instance types do not). However, all Ubuntu 22.04 AMIs use EBS, not Instance Store. If you use the [Ubuntu Amazon EC2 AMI Locator](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) and search for "22.04", you'll find that all of the results have `hvm:ebs-ssd` as the instance type. Only very old Ubuntu AMIs have Instance Store volumes.

Make sure you are using the AMI Locator to find the Ubuntu 22.04 AMI. Those AMIs should work with most or all EC2 instance types.

Comment: Hi Ben, i just have something i do not get is the instance store associated with the instance type or with the AMI , i do not get how AMI have instance store. is not the AMI stored in a root EBS. even if its root is instance store this should not make an issue with instance type ? so can you clarify things for me a bit. @Ben

Comment: Perhaps this comparison chart will help you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html#storage-for-the-root-device

Comment: thx Ben i think i get it now, some AMI instances supports an additional instance store by default, also some instance types supports to add an additional instance store, and if you choose an AMI that has by default an instance store  and you choose an instance type that does not you may get this error as a warning!

Comment: Yup, you got it!  