# "The selected AMI contains more instance store volumes than the instance allows" no matter which AMI I pick

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to set up a g5.4xlarge instance to run AlphaFold on. When going over the storage section, I get the following warning:

The selected AMI contains more instance store volumes than the instance allows. Only the first 1 instance store volumes from the AMI will be accessible from the instance

This happens regardless of the AMI that I choose, and I only see one EBS AMI Root volume and one store-backed instance volume (which seems to match the volume included with a g5.4xlarge instance). I would like to use a deep learning AMI, such as:

Deep Learning AMI GPU PyTorch 1.13.1 (Ubuntu 20.04) 20230103
ami-0b7e0d9b36f4e8f14 (64-bit (x86))

This leaves a few questions:

1. Is this going to interfere with using the AMI?
2. Is the instance storage going to be used at all?
3. If 1, can I fix it?
4. If not 2, why is it included, and would there be a discount available if I could remove it?

I tried several different AMI's, expected at least one to remove the error based on what I read at this answer: [AWS launch new instance using Ubuntu 22.04: image has more volumes than instances allows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73930647/aws-launch-new-instance-using-ubuntu-22-04-image-has-more-volumes-than-instance)
No such luck.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The two answers I have thus far both have part of the answer (not sure which to mark as the answer as a result). Ben Whaley gave a good direct solution for the problem (part 3), while Adil Hidistan gave a great answer to parts 1 and 2. I think I will mark Ben Whaley as the answer as it has the solution to the underlying problem, but I am also thankful for the information that Adil provided to help my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AMI you mentioned, `ami-0b7e0d9b36f4e8f14`, does in fact have two instance store volumes:

[image: PyTorch AMI with two volumes]

Note the two ephemeral volumes under block devices.

It seems that the Amazon Linux 2 images do not have instance store volumes, however. For example, `ami-0dc2e3e2f9cca7c15`. I found this by searching for AMIs matching the phrase `amazon/Deep Learning AMI GPU PyTorch` with a creation date after 2023-01-01.

Comment: How do I get this summary view for other AMIs? I have been looking but not finding

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have is about the instance type you chose. The error is telling you that. chosen instance type [supports 1x instance store volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html), yet the AMI has 2, hence the error.

Now, will that affect your usage. Answer is maybe. It depends on what the intention of the AMI owner was, why they added that volume and if they are actively making use of it when instantiating the instance.

If, for example, their intention was to run a script that will look for that instance volume to store some data, in the absence of it, instance may not boot or not have the features it is meant to have. There is no way of telling unless you understand its purpose and usage.

If you happen to choose an instance type that supports 2x instance store volumes, you will be fine, that's a fix. Otherwise, there is a risk that it won't work as intended.

If you have the ability, open a case with Amazon and have them provide information directly. If you do not have a support agreement, you could try their forums.